# How to convert date from Gregorian to Shamsi

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I get dates (in Gregorian) from `SqlServer` and put them in a `datatable` so I can show it in a `datagridview`,

But before I show them in a DGV, I had to convert them to Shamsi in `datatable`,

First I do that By this Method:

```
public string PersianDate(DateTime DateTime1)
{
    PersianCalendar PersianCalendar1 = new PersianCalendar();
    return string.Format(@"{0}/{1}/{2}",
                 PersianCalendar1.GetYear(DateTime1),
                 PersianCalendar1.GetMonth(DateTime1),
                 PersianCalendar1.GetDayOfMonth(DateTime1));

}
```

And this Code:

```
foreach (DataRow DR in Dtable.Rows)
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DR["VisitDate"]);
    string Pdate = PersianDate(dt);
    DR["VisitDate"] = Pdate;
}
```

and then set `datatable` to DGV,

but it gives time in MM/dd/yyyy format and I want dd/MM/yyyy

so I add this part to `foeach loop`:

```
foreach (DataRow DR in Dtable.Rows)
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DR["VisitDate"]);
    string Pdate = PersianDate(dt);
    DR["VisitDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(Pdate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

and it worked.

but in some days like 3/20/2017 (30/12/1395) => leaf year,
 or even in 3/19/2020 (29/12/1398) => not leaf year

it gives me the error :

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <29/12/1398> in VisitDate Column.  Expected type is DateTime.

So how can I show my date correctly in dd/MM/yyyy Format without any possible error ?

sorry for this long question

Comment: I don't know much anything Persian date systems, so I can't answer your question completely, but I note that you do a *lot* of unnecessary string conversions (for example, `PersianDate` returns a string instead of some date data type). **Never use strings for dates**, always use specialized types (such as `DateTime` and whatever is used to store Persian dates) and all your problems will vanish at once. If you want to display the date in a certain format, use [the formatting options of your UI control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Heinzi  tanks, I deleted unnecessary string conversions and get Persian date in date format, but still i want to show them like dd/MM/yyyy in dgv and I don't know how, (dgv is data bounded)

Comment: You can format the DGV column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the tips in comments. Unnecessary string conversions were deleted.

```
foreach (DataRow DR in Dtable.Rows)
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DR["VisitDate"]);

    PersianDateLibrary.PerCalander Per = new PersianDateLibrary.PerCalander();

    DateTime ct = Convert.ToDateTime(Per.
    GetPersianDate(dt, PersianDateLibrary.PerCalander.DateFormat.Short));

    DR["VisitDate"] = ct;
}
```

Before binding data formating in `dgv` column, do the job:

```
dgv.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Persia.NET Core which is a class library to convert Persian, Gregorian, and Arabic (Hijri) dates to each other.

**Converting Gregorian to Shamsi**

```
Persia.SolarDate solarDate = Persia.Calendar.ConvertToPersian(DateTime.Now);
// getting the simple format of persian date
string str = solarDate.ToString();
```

**Converting Shamsi to Gregorian**

```
DateTime ConvertToGregorian(SolarDate solarDate)
DateTime ConvertToGregorian(LunarDate lunarDate)
DateTime ConvertToGregorian(int year, int month, int day, DateType dateType)
DateTime ConvertToGregorian(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int
second, DateType dateType)
```

The library can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/shahabfar/Persia-.NET-Core)